# access https resource if swf is served from http

Tags: apache-flex, https

My swf is being served via http protocol. I don't really see this being easily changed. There's a resource that a website has opened up via their api that I need to access but it is using https protocol. Because of this my swf can't access the resource because of security settings.

Option 1 would be to serve my swf via https. I can't do this at the moment.

Option 2 would be set secure="false" property of the cross domain policy file. I can't do this, I dont have access.

Is there an option 3 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you can do it with a proxy. Basically, instead of trying to get the remote site with Flash, you use a servers-side script to retrieve the information for you.

Comment: Yeah thats a good one. I was hoping for a flex only solution..... I'm beginning to think thats its pretty unlikey tho

Comment: Have you tried asking the soundcloud forum about this issue? I guess you're not the first one having this problem...

Comment: I pretty much took on your suggestion. Stick a xmlhttprequest for the content in the page at runtime then use external interface to pass the result back to the swf. I guess it is a proxy